# iPhone: pushViewController doesn't work after replacing RootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I wish to place a screen before my curren RootViewController. So far I have made the following modification to `MyAppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //with this in the existing RootViewController loads correctly
    //self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController; 
    self.window.rootViewController = [[[HomePageController alloc] init] autorelease];  
}
```

I'm not entirely sure how self.navigationController actually gets set to my RootViewController.  Either way if I make the modification my `HomePageController` does load correctly, however I am then unable to push another view on top of it.  I have a simple button on `HomePageController` that performs the following (note that `HomePageController` should load the currently named `RootViewController`, `HomePageController` is the view I want to sit above this):

```
RootViewController *rvC = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvC animated:YES];
```

When this code runs nothing happens... I'm not entirely sure why, possibly something related to the navigationController? Maybe I havent put `HomePageController` above `RootViewController` correctly or in the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no navgiationController currently installed.
To fix you have to replace

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[[HomePageController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

with

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[[UINavigatoinController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[HomePageController alloc] init] autorelease]] autorelease];
```

now you have navigationController installed and following

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rvC animated:YES];
```

will do the right job.